# Should I avoid "goto" in situations like this?

Tags: c++, goto

I was making a "concatenating iterator", i.e. an iterator that would  iterate over the `int`s in an `int**`.

Its constructor needs:

- An array of `T**`, representing the beginning of each sub-array.
- An array of `T**`, representing the end of each sub-array.

Lo and behold, I ran across a situation where `goto` seemed to be appropriate.

But something within me screamed "NO!!" so I thought I'd come here and ask:

#### Should I try avoid `goto` situations like this?  (Does it improve the readability if I do?)

```
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
class lazy_concat_iterator
{
    // This code was meant to work for any valid input iterator
    // but for easier reading, I'll assume the type is: T**

    mutable T** m_endIt;              // points to an array of end-pointers
    mutable T** m_it;                 // points to an array of begin-pointers
    mutable bool m_started;   // have we started iterating?
    mutable T* m_sub;         // points somewhere in the current sub-array
    mutable T* m_subEnd;      // points to the end of the current sub-array

public:
    lazy_concat_iterator(T** begins, T** ends)
        : m_it(begins), m_endIt(ends), m_started(false) { }

    void ensure_started() const
    {
        if (!m_started)
        {
            m_started = true;
        
        INIT:
            m_sub = *m_it;
            m_subEnd = *m_endIt;

            if (m_sub == m_subEnd)  // End of this subarray?
            {
                ++m_it;
                ++m_endIt;
                goto INIT;  // try next one         <<< should I use goto here?
            }
        }
    }
};
```

How you could use it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<char*> beginnings(argv, argv + argc);

    vector<char*> endings;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        endings.push_back(argv[i] + strlen(argv[i]));

    lazy_concat_iterator<char> it(&beginnings[0], &endings[0]);
    it.ensure_started();  // 'it' would call this internally, when dereferenced
}
```

Comment: Why not use a loop?  It is, afterall, exactly what you are implementing with a goto and much easier to read,

Comment: @Goz: Well, it would be an *unconditional* `for (;;) { ... }` loop, with a `break;` inside. The lack of a condition makes it seem like a `loop` would be less readable. But is that *actually* more readable than a goto? That's my question.

Comment: I think so. You'd get a block, and more importantly people don't expect to see a goto in code, so you'll throw them off pace with this. Especially if you just end up implementing a loop anyways.

Comment: I agree, `for (;;) { ... if (...) break; ... }` is much better. Save `goto` for implementing FSM's and maybe tail recursion, that's about it's only use.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Ugh, I'm typing this on the fly... it was a typo -- `transform` was supposed to output into `endings`, not into `beginnings`. Fixed.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: No, I'm reducing it from the code I already have (which contains a heck of a lot of `enable_if`s and all that jazz)... I'll fix that too, gimme a couple minutes.

Comment: and you probably don't just want `endings` to contain the result of strlen, you probably want `transform(argv, argv + argc, back_inserter(endings), [](char *arg){return arg + strlen(arg);});`

Comment: @Mehrdad: Why would it be an unconditional for loop?  You can easily create that as a conditional for loop.

Comment: @Goz: You can, but you'd duplicate the condition (I've found duplicating code is a bad idea, especially for someone like me), or you'd introduce an extra variable (which IMO makes it less readable, IMO).

Comment: @Mehrdad: As Charles Bailey points out there is no duplication of condition necessary ... admittedly you would end up 1 past your required iterator position but its a simple matter to decrement your iterator as its a pointer and therefore bi-directional ...

Comment: @Goz: I guess you missed this part: *`// This code was meant to work for any valid input iterator, but for easier reading, I'll assume the type is: T**`*

Comment: @Mehrdad: Iterators are still bi-directional...

Comment: @Goz: I guess you *still* missed it? I wrote: *"for any valid **input** iterator"*, **not** *"for any valid iterator"*. Like I said, I made it a pointer for readability, but that's not the intention.

Comment: @Mehrdad ... fair enough ... you can always store the the last iterator's position into m_sub and m_subEnd prior to the increment and you are sorted.  Still a loop and way less confusing than your goto statement.

Comment: Given that making `ensure_started` `const` requires _every_ member variable to be mutable and that it doesn't even seem to be a conceptually "const" operation I would consider making it a non-const member function.

Comment: @Goz: The equivalent of 5 pointers is way too huge for an iterator to allow it to be efficiently passed around by value, though. In my original code, I was already doing optimizations to reduce the entire thing from 4 to 3 pointers, for the case of forward-or-better iterators. I was hoping to leave input iterators at 4; 5 just seems too big.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Well, it's not a good idea in general since I'm preserving the `const` semantics inside `operator ++` and such... but yes, for illustration here, that might not be such a bad idea.

Comment: @Mehrdad: `operator++` was `const` ?!

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Lol, sorry, bad example. I was referring to the operators in general... `operator *`, `operator ->`, and the gang would be, though.

Comment: @Mehrdad: m_sub and m_subEnd don't actually need to be anything more than local to the if statement.

Comment: @Goz: They're not local, they're instance members... hence the `m_`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: And anyway ... 3 pointers is still too large to pass sensibly by value

Comment: @Goz: It's much better than 5, I think, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Passing anything through a stack copy is inadvisable .. thats why iterators are usually passed by reference ...

Comment: @Goz: I 100% (well, OK, maybe 95%) disagree. Have you heard of copy elision and/or aliasing? If you always pass things by reference you're giving yourself more potential to shoot yourself in the foot in edge cases. Anyway, that argument is tangential to the question here so I don't want to discuss argument passing techniques here.

Comment: @Mehrdad:  AFAIK no compiler elides the copy of a parameter being passed-by-value due to the fundamental nature of parameter passing by value. ie that the parameters needs to be distinct from the original object (ie a copy needs to be made).

Comment: @Goz: GCC begs to differ... http://ideone.com/SSdIs ... but please stop arguing over this on this post since I'll ignore it (it's mostly unrelated and I need to go sleep).

Comment: @Mehrdad:  That object can be passed through a register (and hence copied via the register quickly and simply).  I'd love to see some proper evidence as it would make a huge difference to me as its not something I'm aware of and could improve performance for 99% of the code I end up having to optimise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can and should avoid `goto`, for example this code should do the equivalent for what yours does from the `INIT` label (this also works for input iterators which was a "hidden requirement" as it doesn't dereference `m_it` and `m_endIt` an extra time once the condition is met unlike my previous transformation):

```
while ((m_subIt = *m_it) == (m_subEnd = *m_endIt))
{
    ++m_it;
    ++m_endIt;
}
```

---

**Previous answer attempt:**

Even a forever loop would be clearer and neater than a `goto`. It highlights the obvious "never terminate" possibility even better.

```
    for (;;)
    {
        m_sub = *m_it;
        m_subEnd = *m_endIt;

        if (m_sub != m_subEnd)
            break;

        ++m_it;
        ++m_endIt;
    }
```

Although I don't see why you need to assign to `m_subEnd` and `m_subIt` inside the loop. If you don't you can rewrite this as a while loop:

```
while (*m_it == *m_endIt)
{
    ++m_it;
    ++m_endIt;
}

m_subIt = *m_it;
m_subEnd = *m_endIt;
```

Comment: Well, the only way it would "never terminate" is if there's a bug... but it shouldn't happen if the parameters are correct... Or is that what you meant?

Comment: Regarding your edit: That doesn't do the same thing, as far as I can tell. You need to have traversed the current sub-array before going to the next sub-array; your edit doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The code seems fragile. What if `*m_it` matches `*m_endIt` for the complete range that `m_it` points to (or the range is empty)? There's no check for running off the end of the range. I don't know what input you are passing it and ensuring that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Do you think that's more readable than the goto? Because it makes me pause a bit before I get what it's doing. (A 'yes' is fine, if it is. I just want to know which one's more readable, since that's why I didn't try going that route.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, I'm totally convinced that it's a lot more readable than the `goto` solution. If you don't think so, you don't have to use it of course.

Answer (score 6):

```
while (*m_it == *m_endIt)
{
    ++m_it;
    ++m_endIt;
}

m_sub = *m_it;
m_subEnd = *m_endIt;
```

Comment: @Mehrdad what's different about it?

Comment: @bames53: See my update. It doesn't do the same thing at all, unless I have a bug in my code (which is possible).

Comment: @Mehrdad They still look the same to me. Both loops iterate m_it and m_endIt until they find a non-empty range.

Comment: @bames53: Oops, you're 100% right, I misread it, really sorry about that. (Although, semi-related: see [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921071/should-i-avoid-goto-in-situations-like-this#comment15874216_11921110).)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe no for loop, but maybe a do-while?

```
    do {
        m_sub = *m_it;
        m_subEnd = *m_endIt;

        if (m_sub == m_subEnd)  // End of this subarray?
        {
            ++m_it;
            ++m_endIt;
        }
    } while (m_sub == m_subEnd);
```

If you don't want to do the comparison twice and still avoid using one of goto's stealth cousins break or continue:

```
    bool anotherround = FALSE;
    do {
        m_sub = *m_it;
        m_subEnd = *m_endIt;

        anotherround = m_sub == m_subEnd
        if (anotherround)  // End of this subarray?
        {
            ++m_it;
            ++m_endIt;
        }
    } while (anotherround);
```

With your knowledge of the context I'm sure you can invent better varnames, but that's the idea.

Regarding a goto's influence on readability: for me the main issue with a goto herey is that it forces the programmer to memorize a potential nonlogical movement in the code - all of a sudden the code can jump almost anywhere.  If you use control structures, even if you have to introduce some extra lines or whatnot, the program continues to behave as expected and follow the flow.  And in the long run, that's what readability is all about.

Comment: That duplicates the code for `m_sub == m_subEnd`, though. Duplicating code is even more error-prone than using a goto, especially when the condition is complicated... so I don't want to do that.

Comment: @Mehrdad I only wanted to show to a perfectly equivalent piece of code could be written without goto or its stealth cousins break, continue & friends.  If you do want to get rid of the double condition check you could map it onto a boolean type variable.

Comment: Yeah, but then it's even *more* complicated, which makes me wonder if it's worth doing, in terms of readability.

Comment: @Mehrdad admit it, you **do** love that goto there eh :-)

Comment: Sorry, not really up to speed, must have overread that somewhere. I'll remove the comment.

Comment: @Cubic added a code fragment to make it more obvious what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a goto. The only case when a goto can be forgiven is if you have a complicated function (which you shouldn't have anyways) and you want to have a centralized exit/cleanup part at the end of the function, where you could goto upon different errors at different parts of the function, or fall through upon success.

All in all, you should use a do-while loop here.

Answer (score 0):

People created middle and high level compilers with using assembler(and high-level assembler). Assembler has many jmp jnz jg jl commands act like goto. They made it this far. Cant you do the same? If you can't then you answered your own question.

I cant say the same thing for interpreters.